# Default javax.xml.transform.Transformer changed output for "br" element to XML

Tags: java, xml, dom

A small but change happened in JDK 8 (AdoptOpenJDK / Temurin) between u292 and u332. In u332, DOM to XML conversion of a `br` DOM element emits the string `<br />`. In u292, the Transformer emits the string without the space: `<br/>`.

In the XML specification I found the rules for Tags for empty elements (https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#d0e2480). Do I understand correctly that `<br/>` did not comply with the specification?
(as there must be at least one whitespace between slash and closing greater-than sign)

Comment: I guess they made the change because, although the two outputs are equivalent when the result is parsed as XML, they are not equivalent when it is parsed as HTML5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there may be, but need not be, whitespace immediately preceding the `/>`:

[***Tags for Empty Elements***](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#d0e2480)

> ```
> [44] EmptyElemTag ::= '<' Name (S Attribute)* S? '/>' [WFC: Unique Att Spec]
> ```

The `?` in `S?` means that `S` (whitespace) may optionally appear.

Software should not depend upon the presence or absence whitespace there.